Проблема с авторизацией в telethon
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что через готовую сессию telethon не могу авторизоваться. Но при создании новой - всё в порядке.
Код стынет на client.start(). Вот лог консоли:
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting send loop
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting receive loop
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 7388117588596843092 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (251b1cbbc40)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 100 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling bad salt for message 7388117588596843092
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:1 message(s) will be resent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 7388117588872927992 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (251b1cbbc40)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 100 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 7388117588876923888 to MsgsAck (251b1cbbb50)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotostate:Server sent a very new message with ID 7388117737123039241, ignoring
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotostate:Server sent a very new message with ID 7388117737447701505, ignoring
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
